# Laravel 4 joining table pagination return some empty page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 table: users, mobile_users, throttle.

1. users: id, email, password, ...
2. mobile_users: id, user_id, ....
3. throttle: id, user_id, banned, ...

And here is my code:

```
$mobile_users = DB::table('mobile_users')
            ->join('users', 'mobile_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('throttle', 'mobile_users.user_id', '=', 'throttle.user_id')
            ->where(function($where) use ($query) {
                $where->where('users.first_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('users.last_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
            })
            ->select(
                'mobile_users.*',
                'users.*',
                'throttle.banned'
            )
            ->distinct()
            ->orderBy('mobile_users.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate($limit);
```

This returns some last page with empty content, I just dont know why, can some1 help me out?

**Update**

Here is the result when dd(DB::getQueryLog()) :

> array(7) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(44) "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } ["time"]=> float(6) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(52) "select * from `throttle` where `user_id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } ["time"]=> float(3) } [2]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(45) "select * from `groups` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["time"]=> float(2) } [3]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(229) "select `groups`.*, `users_groups`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `users_groups`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id` from `groups` inner join `users_groups` on `groups`.`id` = `users_groups`.`group_id` where `users_groups`.`user_id` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } ["time"]=> float(3) } [4]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(39) "select * from `payback_configs` limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(5) } [5]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(249) "select count(*) as aggregate from `mobile_users` inner join `users` on `mobile_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `throttle` on `mobile_users`.`user_id` = `throttle`.`user_id` where (`users`.`first_name` LIKE ? or `users`.`last_name` LIKE ?)" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "%%" [1]=> string(2) "%%" } ["time"]=> float(2) } [6]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(344) "select distinct `mobile_users`.*, `users`.*, `throttle`.`banned` from `mobile_users` inner join `users` on `mobile_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `throttle` on `mobile_users`.`user_id` = `throttle`.`user_id` where (`users`.`first_name` LIKE ? or `users`.`last_name` LIKE ?) order by `mobile_users`.`created_at` DESC limit 3 offset 0" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "%%" [1]=> string(2) "%%" } ["time"]=> float(9) } }

Comment: Use `DB::getQueryLog()` to find the actual query generated and update question so people have more of a chance of helping

Comment: Does it work properly when you comment out the `paginate($limit)` call? Does it work when you do `->skip($offset)->take($page_size)` ?

Comment: How you solved this problem?